# not found Glass Development Kit at android Sdk manager

Tags: android

i have read
    https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start

We recommend installing the ADT Bundle for easier development. The rest of these steps assume you have this installed.
Click Window > Android SDK Manager.
Install the SDK Platform and Google GDK Sneak Peek for Android 4.0.3 (API 15). Everything else is optional.

but at my  Sdk manger i cannot find it,i also update my Sdk manger,but also not found.
[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  I even tried downloading the ADT again and it didn't help.

Comment: Now it's showing up for me.  No idea why!

Comment: i am not found already. is your every sdk show it?

Answer (score 2):

This is because, GDK comes in API-19. The minimum requirement for GDK is API-19. Please see this link : [image]https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start

Comment: Still no dice: http://f.cl.ly/items/0q3i013J191v120T3N1o/Screen%20Shot%202014-06-18%20at%201.12.38%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

If you right click and run Android SDK Manager as Administrator, additional items will appear on your list.