# Impossible to create a Glass application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, gdk

When I try to create an application for Google Glass, I can't select Glass on the menu of Android Studio. The "check" is disabled:

[image: Check disabled]

I have the correct path of the SDK assigned to Android Studio, and the API 19 is installed correctly:

[image]

Tests that I have done:

- Change the path of the SDK.
- Uninstall and reinstall the API 19.

Android Studio version: 1.3.2

¿Any suggestion?

I've checked this links:

[StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578348/google-glass-not-installed)

[StackOverflow post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091286/not-found-glass-development-kit-at-android-sdk-manger)

Comment: do you already check your app properties?

Comment: Yes. All apps have a correct properties, but I can't start an app for Google Glass (I can't select the correct option of Android Studio, because the "Glass" option is disabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue after updating Android Studio to the newest release. Fix: Use working version 1.2.1.1 (http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/1-2-1-1)

Comment: I've created the project on other computer with other version of Android Studio and it works. However, I think too that is a bug =) Thanks for your reply!